# Using custom faker data providers without standard doctrine fixtures in Nelmio Alice

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I am setting up [NelmioAlice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) and [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) in a Symfony2 project through [AlixeFixturesBundle](https://github.com/h4cc/AliceFixturesBundle). I need a *composed* fixture like for example:

```
representative{1..100}:
    veeva_rep_id (unique): qlv_005800000067SwzAAE
```

which is a `qlv_` prefix followed by a random 18 characters string. The best way I found to get this done (if anyone knows another one or a better way to get this done let me know) was using a custom faker and I wrote this piece of code:

```
<?php
/**
 * FakerProvider: VeevaProvider.
 */

namespace PDI\PDOneBundle\DataFixtures;

use ReverseRegex\Lexer;
use ReverseRegex\Random\SimpleRandom;
use ReverseRegex\Parser;
use ReverseRegex\Generator\Scope;

class VeevaProvider extends \Faker\Provider\Base
{
    public function veevaRepId()
    {
        $lexer = new  Lexer('[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}');
        $gen = new SimpleRandom(10007);
        $result = '';

        $parser = new Parser($lexer, new Scope(), new Scope());
        $parser->parse()->getResult()->generate($result, $gen);

        return 'qlv_' . $result;
    }
}
```

As explain [here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#faker-internals-understanding-providers) in Faker docs. Now, [here](https://github.com/nelmio/alice#custom-faker-data-providers) at NelmioAlice the author explain how to add *Custom Faker Data Providers* but it uses Doctrine Fixtures which I don't so, having this, how do I load and use the provider I wrote on the fixtures? Any advice around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as passing an instance of the provider into the `Loader` when you construct it:

`$loader = new Loader('en_US', [new VeeveProvider]);`

Comment: Where exactly is that `Loader`? By loader you mean a set file for example?

Comment: @AngeloA no I didn't, did you have any code to show me?

Comment: @ReynierPM No. I'm looking for a solution. Can't find it anywhere on the net.